# How to save a non-ggplot plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, metafor

I have a forest plot from the package `metafor`. As it's not a ggplot, I cannot use my favourite `ggsave()`.
I have tried functions like `png(filename="forest_plot_bmj.png", res=315, width=3312, height=1228)` but the outcome I get is different than what I see in the console output.
What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Do you have some code and data to reproduce?

Comment: @Quinten Unfortunately not! :( The real data is confidential.

Comment: Or a reproducible sample data?

Comment: In Windows there is `savePlot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R plots, one needs to define the start of the plotting action e.g. with `png` and the end of the plotting with `dev.off()`:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)

png("out.png")
forest(dat$yi, dat$vi)
dev.off()
```